# Which reduced rings have the following property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, affine-schemes

Let us say a given commutative ring $R$ has property $\mathcal{P}$
if for every two elements $f,g \in R\setminus 0$, there exists a prime ideal $q \subset R$ such that both $f \notin q$ and $g \notin q$.

Note: obviously if $R$ has nontrivial nilradical then $R$ doesn't have property $\mathcal{P}$.

I was wondering, can anyone provide an example of $R$ reduced (i.e. having trivial nilradical) but still failing to have property $\mathcal{P}$?

Also, does the above property hold if $R$ is a reduced algebra (unital, assoc, comm) over a field?

Note: my motivation for considering this property is, if I'm not mistaken: if $R$ has property $\mathcal{P}$ then the intersection of any two nonempty distinguished opens is nonempty. Since the distinguished opens form a base, it follows that every open set of $\mathrm{Spec}R$ is dense.

Comment: Are you the same person as https://math.stackexchange.com/users/896770/indraneel-tambe?  If so, why do you have a second account?  You should be aware that it is against the rules to use multiple accounts to do anything that you could not do with a single account (e.g., voting on your own posts, or voting twice on someone else's post).

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes that is also my account. Sure, I understand; I have not been doing any rule infractions such as that. Rather, I created a separate account because of reaching question limits on the first account.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is against the rules as well--exceeding the question limits is something you cannot do with a single account so you are not allowed to do so using an additional account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be your favorite field, and consider the $F$-algebra $R=F[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle$. This ring is reduced, but it does not have property $\mathcal{P}$, since every prime ideal of $R$ has to contain one of the non-zero elements $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask, in this case, does there exist some $f \in R$ such that the distinguished open set $D(f) = \{ p \in \mathrm{Spec}R : f\notin p\}$ is not dense in $\mathrm{Spec}R$?

Comment: @IndraneelTambe2 my pleasure, happy it helped! :) and yes, indeed that is correct. if $f=\bar{x}$, then every element of $D(f)$ contains $\bar{y}$. thus in other words $D(f)$ is contained in the proper closed subset $V(\bar{y})$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and is hence not dense

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!

Comment: @IndraneelTambe2 my pleasure, happy it helped! :)